# SQL Server 2012 Metadata Syntax

Tags: sql-server

Sorry for the dumb question in advance and thanks for your time!

I have two queries

**Query A**

```
 SELECT sc.name +'.'+ta.name TableName
    ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
FROM sys.tables ta
INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
ON pa.object_id = ta.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
ON ta.schema_id=sc.schema_id
WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
ORDER BY sum(pa.rows) DESC;
```

and

**Query B**

```
SELECT ta.name TableName
, ta.modify_date ModDate
, ta.max_column_id_used "Columns"
FROM sys.tables ta
ORDER BY ta.name;
```

which execute fine.

When I add the lines

```
, ta.modify_date ModDate
, ta.max_column_id_used "Columns"
```

I create **Query C**

```
SELECT sc.name +'.'+ta.name TableName
    ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
    , ta.modify_date ModDate
    , ta.max_column_id_used "Columns"
FROM sys.tables ta
INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
ON pa.object_id = ta.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
ON ta.schema_id=sc.schema_id
WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
ORDER BY sum(pa.rows) DESC;
```

I get the error

> 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Column 'sys.tables.modify_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I understand what aggregate fx are as well as the purpose of GROUP BY.

Do I need to create a subquery to include this information in one query

Comment: `..Group by sc.name,ta.name,ta.modify_date,ta.max_column_id_used`

Comment: Thumb rule of `Group by` : The **Non Aggregate** columns in `Select` list **should** be part of `Group By`

Comment: thanks! that absolutely worked!